# How can I set background color per tick by MQL4?

Tags: mql4, mql

How can I set background color per tick like following by MQL4?
I couldn't find in documentation.
https://mt4trader.net/wp-content/uploads/2015-08-17_hikinashibg.jpg

Comment: I think you have to draw many rectangles in such a case with `PRICE_1` = 0 and `PRICE_2` = (some large value or `INT_MAX`) and update the latest rectangle at least once per bar

Comment: @DanielKniaz Thank you. I think this is the answer. I'll try to do this!

Answer (score 0):

I use array of colors and a static variable in the `OnTick` function to pick new color upon every call for the function. the same logic can be used for any function you'll define outside the `OnTick` function. A static variable will enable you to keep a value of the index of the used color from the array in the function after execution.